# Javascript - assign variable or array from outside file

Tags: arrays

This past year, I took a coding class on creating games using javascript. It is a basic game  like Asteroids. When the game ends, it shows the top 5 high scores. The only problem is that when the program is restarted, the array that holds the scores is reset.

I want to store the high scores in a text file or spreadsheet. But, I cannot find a way to get my program to pull information from an outside file and assign it to either a variable, or I would rather put it into an array.

The second part is that when the game ends, it would need to send the updated array to the outside file if it is updated. Everything I look up involves HTML and CSS and we didn't learn this.

Is there any viable way to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the question is 'how do I read and write files from javascript'? The answer largely depends on where you're running the Javascript.

It doesn't sound like you're working in a browser, which makes it likely that you're using [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/). If this is the case, you'll want to look at the [File System API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#file-system). Specifically, you'll want to create a filehandle by using [`fsPromises.open()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesopenpath-flags-mode). Once you have this reference to a location on your hard drive, you'll use [`filehandle.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlewritefiledata-options) to write a string directly to the file, and [`filehandle.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions) to read a string directly from the same file.